# Can we use adverb phrase with conjunction plus noun phrase?

Tags: adverbs, ellipsis, adverbial-phrases

> I could not remember him; but I knew that he was my own uncle—my
>   mother’s brother—that he had taken me **when a parentless infant** to his
>   house; and that in his last moments he had required a promise of Mrs.
>   Reed that she would rear and maintain me as one of her own children.
>   (Jane Eyre)

Can we use adverb phrase like the highlighted: conjunction plus noun phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s an instance of ellipsis, in which elements of a clause or phrase are not expressed. In the example, ‘when a parentless infant’ would, in full, be ‘when **I was** a parentless infant’.

Comment: Is `Ellipsis` and `implicit` words are same?

Comment: @Mistu4u. The missing words are implicit, but ellipsis is the grammatical feature.